# Prevent DeferredTask from retrying if it fails in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I noticed that the com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.DeferredTask in the Google Cloud retries if it throws an exception. Is there a way to have it not retry if it gets an error?

Note: using JAVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With first gen GAE and Python, you can specify options to the deferred call like this:

```
retry = taskqueue.TaskRetryOptions(task_retry_limit=0)
deferred.defer(..., _retry_options=retry)
```

This will prevent the task from being retried.

If you are using second gen GAE, please update your question to indicate that.

Comment: I'm not sure what gen I am on. Is there a way to check in the google cloud console or elsewhere? Also I am on Java.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/DeferredTask), I see this in [Interface DeferredTask](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/DeferredTask) which I think you may be able to use:

> Normal return from this method is considered success and will not
> retry unless [DeferredTaskContext.markForRetry()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/DeferredTaskContext.html#markForRetry--) is called.
> Exceptions thrown from this method will indicate a failure and will be
> processed as a retry attempt unless
> [DeferredTaskContext.setDoNotRetry(boolean)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/DeferredTaskContext.html#setDoNotRetry-boolean-) was set to true.